# craft.matrixBlocks() by section

Tags: matrix

Trying to grab the total count of matrix blocks that belong to a section. Looks like there is no section parameter for craft.matrixBlocks(). Not sure as to why that is.

Anyone know of another way that isn't convoluted i.e. looping through craft.entries and building array?

```
{% set totalBlocksEnabled = craft.matrixBlocks()
.status('enabled')
.site(siteHandle)
.type(type)
.field('blocks')
.total() %}
```

No section parameter.
https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/matrix-blocks.html#querying-matrix-blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go via `entries()` and do something like this:

```twig
{% set blockCount = craft.entries()
    .section('yourSectionHandle')
    .with([
        ['matrixFieldHandle', {type: 'blockHandle'}]
    ])
    .all() | map(b => b.blocks | length) | reduce((carry, v) => carry + v) %}
```

In short, `map` ([docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/map.html)) builds an array of block count/per entry and `reduce` ([docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/reduce.html)) sums it all up.

Eager-loading the blocks using `with` will only return enabled blocks.